# Testing onChange using Enzyme, Sinon and Chai- onChange is not called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, chai, sinon

I'm trying to write some tests for [rc-select](https://www.google.com/search?q=rc-select&oq=rc-select&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l4j0i10j69i60j69i61j69i60.2915j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

The test I'm trying to do is checking that the onChange function is called.
What I have so far:

The test component, which uses a styled version of rc-select:

**ReactSelectTestComponent.jsx**

```js
import React from 'react';
import Select from '../../packages/lab/src/select/Select.jsx';

const ReactSelectTestComponent = (props) => {

    const { options } = props;

    const onChange = (event) => {
        if (props.onChange) {
            props.onChange(event)
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Select
                name='test'
                value='one'
                options={options}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
        </div >
    )
}


export default ReactSelectTestComponent;
```

**Select.test.js:**

```js
import SelectTestComponent from './SelectTestComponent'
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { expect as chaiExpect } from 'chai';  // Using Expect style

describe('Testing Select component', () => {

    it('should call onChange', () => {
        const onChange = sinon.spy();
        const options =
            [
                { label: 'one', value: 'one' },
                { label: 'two', value: 'two' }
            ];
        const wrapper = mount(<SelectTestComponent onChange={onChange} options={options} />);
        console.log("wrapper.debug()", wrapper.debug())

        const selectWrapper = wrapper.find('Select').first();
        selectWrapper.simulate('change', { target: { value: "testtest" } })
        selectWrapper.update()

        chaiExpect(onChange.called).to.be.true;
    });
})
```

**However, I'm getting this error.**

```
Expected value   true
    Received:
      false
    
    Message:
      expected false to be true

      38 |         selectWrapper.update()
      39 | 
    > 40 |         chaiExpect(onChange.called).to.be.true;
         |         ^
      41 |     });
      42 | 
      43 |     /*

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/src/Select.test.js:40:9)
```

Is there another selector I should be using in the find() call? I feel like I have tried every option.

**console.log(wrapper.debug()):**

```
ReactSelectTestComponent options={{...}}>
        <div>
          <ForwardRef name="test" value="one" options={{...}} onChange={[Function: onChange]} menuItemSelectedIcon={{...}}>
            <Memo(l) />
            <Styled(Select) className={[undefined]} value="one" inputIcon={{...}} menuItemSelectedIcon={{...}} name="test" onChange={[Function: onChange]}>
              <Select className="sc-kBqltT caYcRD" value="one" inputIcon={{...}} menuItemSelectedIcon={{...}} name="test" onChange={[Function: onChange]}>
                <ForwardRef(Select) className="sc-kBqltT caYcRD" value="one" inputIcon={{...}} menuItemSelectedIcon={{...}} name="test" onChange={[Function: onChange]}>
                  <div className="rc-select sc-kBqltT caYcRD rc-select-single rc-select-show-arrow" name="test" onMouseDown={[Function: onInternalMouseDown]} onKeyDown={[Function: onInternalKeyDown]} onKeyUp={[Function: onInternalKeyUp]} onFocus={[Function: onContainerFocus]} onBlur={[Function: onContainerBlur]}>
                    <SelectTrigger disabled={[undefined]} prefixCls="rc-select" visible={[undefined]} popupElement={{...}} containerWidth={{...}} animation={[undefined]} transitionName={[undefined]} dropdownStyle={[undefined]} dropdownClassName={[undefined]} direction={[undefined]} dropdownMatchSelectWidth={[undefined]} dropdownRender={[undefined]} dropdownAlign={[undefined]} getPopupContainer={[undefined]} empty={false} getTriggerDOMNode={[Function: getTriggerDOMNode]}>
                      <Trigger showAction={{...}} hideAction={{...}} popupPlacement="bottomLeft" builtinPlacements={{...}} prefixCls="rc-select-dropdown" popupTransitionName={[undefined]} popup={{...}} popupAlign={{...}} popupVisible={[undefined]} getPopupContainer={[undefined]} popupClassName="" popupStyle={{...}} getTriggerDOMNode={[Function: getTriggerDOMNode]} getPopupClassNameFromAlign={[Function: returnEmptyString]} getDocument={[Function: returnDocument]} onPopupVisibleChange={[Function: noop]} afterPopupVisibleChange={[Function: noop]} onPopupAlign={[Function: noop]} mouseEnterDelay={0} mouseLeaveDelay={0.1} focusDelay={0} blurDelay={0.15} destroyPopupOnHide={false} defaultPopupVisible={false} mask={false} maskClosable={true} action={{...}} autoDestroy={false}>
                        <Selector className="sc-kBqltT caYcRD" value="one" inputIcon={{...}} menuItemSelectedIcon={{...}} name="test" onChange={[Function: onChange]} domRef={{...}} prefixCls="rc-select" inputElement={{...}} id="rc_select_TEST_OR_SSR" showSearch={false} mode={[undefined]} accessibilityIndex={0} multiple={false} tagRender={[undefined]} values={{...}} open={[undefined]} onToggleOpen={[Function: onToggleOpen]} searchValue="" activeValue={{...}} onSearch={[Function: triggerSearch]} onSearchSubmit={[Function: onSearchSubmit]} onSelect={[Function: onInternalSelectionSelect]} tokenWithEnter={false} onContextMenu={[undefined]} onClick={[undefined]} onMouseDown={[undefined]} onTouchStart={[undefined]} onMouseEnter={[undefined]} onMouseLeave={[undefined]} onFocus={[undefined]} onBlur={[undefined]}>
                          <div className="rc-select-selector" onClick={[Function: onClick]} onMouseDown={[Function: onMouseDown]}>
                            <SingleSelector className="sc-kBqltT caYcRD" value="one" inputIcon={{...}} menuItemSelectedIcon={{...}} name="test" onChange={[Function: onChange]} domRef={{...}} prefixCls="rc-select" inputElement={{...}} id="rc_select_TEST_OR_SSR" showSearch={false} mode={[undefined]} accessibilityIndex={0} multiple={false} tagRender={[undefined]} values={{...}} open={[undefined]} onToggleOpen={[Function: onToggleOpen]} searchValue="" activeValue={{...}} onSearch={[Function: triggerSearch]} onSearchSubmit={[Function: onSearchSubmit]} onSelect={[Function: onInternalSelectionSelect]} tokenWithEnter={false} onContextMenu={[undefined]} onClick={[undefined]} onMouseDown={[undefined]} onTouchStart={[undefined]} onMouseEnter={[undefined]} onMouseLeave={[undefined]} onFocus={[undefined]} onBlur={[undefined]} inputRef={{...}} onInputKeyDown={[Function: onInternalInputKeyDown]} onInputMouseDown={[Function: onInternalInputMouseDown]} onInputChange={[Function: onInputChange]} onInputPaste={[Function: onInputPaste]} onInputCompositionStart={[Function: onInputCompositionStart]} onInputCompositionEnd={[Function: onInputCompositionEnd]}>
                              <span className="rc-select-selection-search">
                                <Input prefixCls="rc-select" id="rc_select_TEST_OR_SSR" open={[undefined]} inputElement={{...}} disabled={[undefined]} autoFocus={[undefined]} autoComplete={[undefined]} editable={false} accessibilityIndex={0} value="" onKeyDown={[Function: onInternalInputKeyDown]} onMouseDown={[Function: onInternalInputMouseDown]} onChange={[Function: onChange]} onPaste={[Function: onInputPaste]} onCompositionStart={[Function: onInputCompositionStart]} onCompositionEnd={[Function: onInputCompositionEnd]} tabIndex={[undefined]} attrs={{...}}>
                                  <input id="rc_select_TEST_OR_SSR" disabled={[undefined]} tabIndex={[undefined]} autoComplete="off" type="search" autoFocus={[undefined]} className="rc-select-selection-search-input" style={{...}} role="combobox" aria-expanded={[undefined]} aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="rc_select_TEST_OR_SSR_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="rc_select_TEST_OR_SSR_list" aria-activedescendant="rc_select_TEST_OR_SSR_list_0" value="" readOnly={true} unselectable="on" onKeyDown={[Function: onKeyDown]} onMouseDown={[Function: onMouseDown]} onChange={[Function: onChange]} onCompositionStart={[Function: onCompositionStart]} onCompositionEnd={[Function: onCompositionEnd]} onPaste={[Function: onInputPaste]} />
                                </Input>
                              </span>
                              <span className="rc-select-selection-item" title="one">
                                one
                              </span>
                            </SingleSelector>
                          </div>
                        </Selector>
                      </Trigger>
                    </SelectTrigger>
                    <TransBtn className="rc-select-arrow" customizeIcon={{...}} customizeIconProps={{...}}>
                      <span className="rc-select-arrow" onMouseDown={[Function: onMouseDown]} style={{...}} unselectable="on" onClick={[undefined]} aria-hidden={true}>
                        <styled.div>
                          <div className="sc-ezjryM fUxvmA">
                            <ForwardRef type="chevron_down" color="#dcdcdc" size={24} rotation={0}>
                              <styled.span className={[undefined]} color="#dcdcdc" width={24} height={24} rotation={0}>
                                <span className="sc-cGKHXZ jHIRgh" color="#dcdcdc" width={24} height={24}>
                                  <svg fill="currentcolor" border="currentcolor" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path fillRule="evenodd" clipRule="evenodd" d="M7.41 8.295l4.59 4.58 4.59-4.58L18 9.705l-6 6-6-6 1.41-1.41z" />
                                  </svg>
                                </span>
                              </styled.span>
                            </ForwardRef>
                          </div>
                        </styled.div>
                      </span>
                    </TransBtn>
                  </div>
                </ForwardRef(Select)>
              </Select>
            </Styled(Select)>
          </ForwardRef>
        </div>
      </ReactSelectTestComponent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working test:** (Needed to call the onChange through props of the wrapper.

```
    it("Checking if onChange prop function is called", () => {
        const onChange = sinon.spy();
        const wrapper = mount(
            <SelectTestComponent onChange={onChange} options={options} />
        );

        const func = wrapper.find("Select").props().onChange;

        console.log(wrapper.find("Select").props());
        func({ target: { value: "test" } });
        chaiExpect(onChange.called).to.be.true;
    });
```